# Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 12 - Link Verification

Tags: python

The [project outline](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter12/):

> Write a program that, given the URL of a web page, will attempt to
> download every linked page on the page. The program should flag any
> pages that have a 404 “Not Found” status code and print them out as
> broken links.

My solution:

```
# Usage: python link_verification.py "webpage to search" 

import sys, requests, bs4

def link_validator(links):
    for link in links:
        page = link.get("href")
        if str(page).startswith("https://"):
            url = link.get("href")
            res = requests.get(url)
            try:
                res.raise_for_status()
                print(f"Page found: {page}")
            except Exception as exc:
                print(f"There was a problem with {page}:\n{exc}")
def main():
    while True:
        url = sys.argv[1] # Enter a website to search
        res = requests.get(url)
        try:
            res.raise_for_status()
        except Exception as exc:
                print(f"There was a problem: {exc}")
                continue
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
        links = soup.select("a")
        link_validator(links)
        print("Search complete")
        break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far, I think your code looks really good. It's clear and easy to read, you are using library code to reduce boilerplate (`r.raise_for_status`), and you have an `if __name__` guard. Nice work! A few things I'd consider:

## `while True: break`

You don't need the loop in your `main` function, since it only goes through a single iteration unless there's a problem with the URL. In that case, I'd probably just `raise` rather than `continue`.

## `sys` args

It's usually more conventional to unpack sys args in the `if __name__` block and pass them as arguments to `main`. This way there isn't a weird side effect if you want to use this function in another module:

```py
def main(url):
    res = requests.get(url) 
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = sys.argv[1]
    main(url)
```

## `if` guards on loops:

When using a `for` loop, it's common to see this kind of pattern:

```py
for thing in iterable:
    if condition:
       # do things
```

While this is easy to understand and straightforward, it can be a little cleaner and avoid extra indentation to check the negative case and skip it:

```py
for thing in iterable:
    if not condition:
        continue

    # do things, note no else
```

So in your `link_validator`:

```py
def link_validator(links):
    for link in links:
        page = link.get("href")
        if not str(page).startswith('https://'):
            continue

        url = link.get("href")
        res = requests.get(url)
        try:
            res.raise_for_status()
            print(f"Page found: {page}")
        except Exception as exc:
            print(f"There was a problem with {page}:\n{exc}")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `page` and `url` variables inside of `link_validator(links)` are redundant. `url` could be removed and `requests.get(url) -> requests.get(page)`.

#### Requests error handling

request's helper `raise_for_status` is great and you're using it well! A small improvement here would be catching *explicit* errors though as catching all exceptions like `except Exception` could have unintended side effects.

For example, if you accidentally typo'd within the `try` block and had `res.raise_for_sttus()`, your code here will handle that and not error. Similarly so for a typo'd, undefined variable name which normally throws a `NameError`

Additionally, just stringifying an error instance *usually* loses the specific error type which is probably fine when you're only catching a particular type of error but when you're catching all errors, it can have very ambiguous side effects. Take the following as an example:

```py
urls = {"a": "http://google.com", "b": "https://stackexchange.com"}
try:
    requests.get(urls["c"])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# prints the following
# 'c'

# or perhaps easier to play with
try:
    d = {}
    print(d['hi'])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# prints
# 'hi'

print(d['hi'])
# raises a KeyError: 'hi'  - notice without the exception type, the message is very ambiguous
```

These may seem like silly examples but I've seen these in production code at a much larger scale produce very hard to find bugs.

So that's all to say you should `except requests.exceptions.HTTPError` in favor of `Exception`.

Finally, it likely makes sense to report on any/all "broken" links, but your prompt does specifically only callout reporting `404`s:

> flag any pages that have a 404 “Not Found” status code and print them out as broken links

Depending on server implementations, `raise_for_status` *may* inappropriately raise depending on how you define "broken link", but either way your code will flag more than only 404's so if you wanted to limit to only 404 status codes or just handle a 404 *differently*, you can do so by checking the `status_code` of the response which you can do in 2 ways:

```py
res = requests.get(...)

if res.status_code == 404:
    print(f"this {page} was not found.")

# or 
try:
    res.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
    if e.response.status_code == 404:
        print(f"this {page} was not found")
    raise e  # or maybe just print("this page was broken but found")
```